# Javascript Vue.js increment value to change state of task in todo app

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

i am creating a todo app using Vue.js with Vuetify library. I have a chip that shows the state of each task. I add a button (v-btn) outside of the chips with the changeState() when on clicked.

My current problem is , my task's state is 'not started' but when i pressed the button, it does not change its state. my expect result is after pressed , it will change the state from 'not started' to 'ongoing' and when i press the same button again it will change from 'ongoing' to 'completed'

the state value of each state is not started = 0, ongoing = 1, completed = 2

HTML:

```
     <v-btn depressed color="white" @click="changeState">
      <div align="center" class="mt-2">
       <v-chip small class="v-chip--active white--text caption my-2" :color="task.status">
        {{task.status}}
       </v-chip>
       </div>
      </v-btn>
```

Javascript:

```
  let id = 1
  let state
  let stateValue = 0

  if (stateValue == 0){
    state = 'not started'
  }
  if (stateValue == 1){
    state = 'ongoing'
  }
  if (stateValue == 2) {
    state = 'completed'
  }

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        newTask: '',
        tasks: [
          { id: id++, title: 'Task 1', status: state, value: stateValue},
          { id: id++, title: 'Task 2', status: state, value: stateValue },
          { id: id++, title: 'Task 3', status: state, value: stateValue },
        ],
      }
    },
    methods: {
      addTask() {
        this.tasks.push({ id: id++, title: this.newTask, status: state, value: 0})
        this.newTask = ''
      },
      removeTask(task) {
        this.tasks = this.tasks.filter((t) => t !== task)
      },
      changeState() {
        
        if (stateValue <= 2) {
          stateValue++
        }
      },
    }
  }
```

Comment: add full code otherwise, it will be difficult to understanding your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update the status of the corresponding task - not the global variable `stateValue`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id" depressed color="white" @click="changeState(task)">
      <div align="center" class="mt-2">
        <v-chip small class="v-chip--active white--text caption my-2" :color="statusName[task.status]">
          {{ statusName[task.status] }}
        </v-chip>
      </div>
    </v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default
{
  name: 'MyCustomComponent',
  data()
  {
    return {
      tasks: [
        { id: 1, title: 'Task 1', status: 0 },
        { id: 2, title: 'Task 2', status: 0 },
        { id: 3, title: 'Task 3', status: 0 },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed:
  {
    statusName()
    {
      return [
        'not started',
        'ongoing',
        'completed',
      ];
    }
  },
  methods:
  {
    changeState(task)
    {
      task.status < 2 && task.status++;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The output result is as expected